How to change SonarQube Quality Gate, add tag and make Sonar Project Public to private using gitlab-ci.yaml
I am trying to change SonarQube Quality Gate, add tag and make Sonar Project Public to private using gitlab-ci.yaml:
      SONAR_QUALITYGATE_NAME: "Cybersecurity_QG_Default"
      SONAR_VISIBILITY: "PRIVATE"
      #SONAR_CONFIG : '-Dsonar.qualitygate.timeout=360 -Dsonar.java.binaries=.'
      SONAR_CONFIG : "-Dsonar.qualitygate.timeout=360 -Dsonar.java.binaries=. -Dsonar.visibility=$SONAR_VISIBILITY -Dsonar.projectTags=${PROJECT_NAME}_${SERVICE_NAME} -Dsonar.qualitygate=$SONAR_QUALITYGATE_NAME"

in template file:
    sonarqube scan:
      stage: code scan
      image: $DOMAIN_NAME/hubdocker/sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
      tags:
        - docker
      variables:
        SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
        SONAR_QUALITYGATE_NAME: "Cybersecurity_QG_Default"
        SONAR_VISIBILITY: "private"
    
      script:
        #- echo $SONAR_VISIBILITY ${PROJECT_NAME}_${SERVICE_NAME $SONAR_QUALITYGATE_NAME
        - echo parameter $SONAR_CONFIG
        - cat /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
        - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=$PROJECT_NAME-$SERVICE_NAME -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=https://$DOMAIN_NAME_SAST -Dsonar.login=$SONARQUBE_TOKEN -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.visibility=PRIVATE -Dsonar.projectTags="DevOps" -Dsonar.qualitygate=Cybersecurity_QG_Default $SONAR_CONFIG
        - cat /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
        - echo End
      allow_failure: true
      only:
        - develop

But SonarQube is still showing visibility public, no Tags added and no Quality Gate changed to Cybersecurity_QG_Default!
Gilab Console Output:
WARN: Property 'sonar.visibility' with value 'PRIVATE' is overridden with value 'private' WARN: Property 'sonar.projectTags' with value 'DevOps' is overridden with value 'fik-test_java' WARN: Property 'sonar.qualitygate' with value 'Cybersecurity_QG_Default' is overridden with value 'Cybersecurity_QG_Default'

SonarQube Project information shows:

